# Python Web Scraping Unterminated String

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am attempting to run a for loop on a list of urls (links) to scrape and convert the html data in 'script' into a format where I can extract the "htmlOutputFileUrl". However, whenever I run the code, I get the error "JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 2998 (char 2997)", and cannot even attempt to extract that information.

Am I unable to convert the 'script' the way shown below or is my code formatted incorrectly?

The first url I am using is: 'http:/www.kaggle.com/kanncaa1/data-sciencetutorial-for-beginners'

```
import requests
import json
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

for url in links:

        test = requests.get(url)
        getTest=test.text
        data = BeautifulSoup(getTest, "lxml")
        update = data.find('div',class_='site-layout__main-content').find('script').text.split(";")
        dataLoad = json.loads((update[2][update[2].index('{'):len(update[2])-1]))
        print (dataLoad)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting on `;`, but there is one in the middle of the JSON object you are trying to extract, so this splits the object in two. You could combine elements 2 and 3 to get the desired result:

```
raw_data = update[2][update[2].index('{')] + update[3][:-1]
```

Note though I doubt you will be able to get this to work; there is no guarantee you have a valid JSON object there at all, note especially that JSON is much more restrictive than JavaScript itself.